# Fast Data Structure For Point Interval Lookups

Tags: data-structures, intervals

I have an interesting problem I'm working on right now and wonder if anyone has had success in implementing high performance solutions to it.

I have a set of "intervals" meaning an array of arrays each of the form

```
Intervals = [
     [min_val_1, max_val_1],
     [min_val_2, max_val_2],
     ...
     [min_val_n, max_val_n]
]
```

Where all these values are real valued.  Now I have a number and I want to ask, which intervals contain this numbers?  And I need to be able to answer this very quickly.  I can preprocess as much as needed and space is less of a consideration than time.  What approach would you recommend?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)